# Which one is correct here: dabei or damit?

Tags: word-usage, conjunction

I've just had a small talk with someone and he asked me "Brauchst du Hilfe **dabei**?" and it was completely understandable of course and the conversation kept going on but after that I was thinking about the question myself if it was correct or not. Then I wanted to ask the question here.

Normally, I would say "Brauchst du Hilfe **damit**?" because in my mind I would've said it in English like "Do you need help **with it**?". Therefore I would use "damit" since I would use "with it" in English counterpart obviously but when I check with online translators and do some sentence search, I saw that it's mostly used with "dabei".

Any ideas why and would it be normal to use **damit** instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, in every day conversation there is not much of a difference. Both *dabei* and *damit* are common in this context and will be understood when interchanged.

The difference may be one of style. For example, when speaker A puts the focus on an action or a process, it might be more apt for speaker B to use *dabei*:

> A: Ich habe Probleme *bei* meinen Hausaufgaben (also *beim* Erledigen der Hausaufgaben).
>
> B: Brauchst du Hilfe *dabei*?

When A puts the focus on the object that makes problems, it might be more apt for B to use *damit*:

> A: Ich habe Probleme *mit* meinem Auto.
>
> B: Brauchst du Hilfe *damit*?

Often, the pronominal adverb is simply omitted:

> B: Brauchst du Hilfe?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. That makes sense actually because I was trying to pull something so there was an "action". Maybe it's better to omit the adverb and just use "Brauchst du Hilfe?". Thanks again.